# Zeroes instead of blanks with relative date filter

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to figure out a way to display an aggregate measure by calendar quarter (a simple count). In the matrix I put a relative date filter (Release Date, is in the last, 1, year). So it should only show in the column headers 2019 Q4, 2020 Q1, 2020 Q2, and 2020 Q3.

I then use a measure to calculate the count and have the return statement with the condition IF(ISBLANK("MEASURE"),0,"MEASURE") in an attempt for power bi to return a zero for those quarters where no data is present.

But the result of this is that my matrix presents ALL quarter going back to 2018 Q1.
[image]

Is there a way to show zeroes in just the quarters present in the last year (relative to todays date)?

This is what I get with a "simple" measure (note that the relative date filter applies).

[image]

What I want to achieve is that for supplier #1 2019 Q4 shows 0, and for 2020 Q1 and Q3 show also the zeroes. Supplier # 2 would show zeroes for 2020 Q1, Q2, and Q3.

Juan

Edit after using the date dimension table:

Now the output looks like this

[image]

But I'm having to use columns from my date table and not the date field from the relationship of my fact table to date table.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a separate calendar table?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a separate calendar table, you need to put the relative date filter on your calendar table, not your data table.

---

Also, instead of using IF in your measure like

```
Measure =
IF ( ISBLANK ( COUNT ( Table1[Col1] ) ), 0, COUNT ( Table1[Col1] ) )
```

since `BLANK() + 0 = 0` you can just write

```
Measure = COUNT ( Table1[Col1] ) + 0
```

Comment: Ok, I put the relative date using the date dimension table, but it is not filtering the date using on my fact table, to make it work I had to use the Year and Quarter Columns of my date table but this way I lose some functionality if I wanted to couple the table with a visual that needs a date field for the axis.

Comment: It sounds like you want a date hierarchy. https://gcomsolutions.co.uk/blog/power-bi/power-bi-hierarchies/